# Script en bat o vbscript para cargar un subarbol en regedit y borrar claves

Tags: script, powershell, .bat, registro-windows

Hola a todos necesito crear un script para que haga lo siguiente en el registro de windows, he intentado hacerlo pero no me sale :( :

Busque y seleccione este subárbol:
HKEY_USERS

En el menú Archivo, seleccione Cargar subárbol.

Nota

El subárbol de usuario predeterminado no está presente de forma predeterminada. Se debe cargar, editar y descargar manualmente.

Escriba C:\Users\Default\NTUSER. DAT en el cuadro Nombre de archivo y seleccione Abrir.

En el cuadro de diálogo Cargar Subárbol, escriba un nombre temporal DefaultUser en el cuadro Nombre de clave y presione Entrar.

Elimine estas entradas del Registro:

HKEY_USERS<DefaultUser>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\FileAssociationsUpdateVersion
HKEY_USERS<DefaultUser>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations
HKEY_USERS<DefaultUser>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts

Ir a HKEY_USERS<DefaultUser>.

En el menú Archivo, seleccione Descargar Subárbol.

Cierre el Editor del Registro.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Me parece muy peligroso.  Dudo que pueda hacerlo con un bat.  Tal vez con PowerShell.

Comment: podes romper cosa con [reg](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg)

Comment: ¿Alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Hola @RubenLL, Lo que necesitas es un archivo .reg o en su lugar usar powershell para acceder a metodos que lo modifiquen. De todas formas sin un ejemplo/codigo minimo nadie te podrá ayudar, podrias comenzar aportando un trozo de codigo como punto de partida, además te dejo un par de links interesantes sobre tu pregunta. https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/09/11/how-to-get-edit-create-and-delete-registry-keys-with-powershell/   los .reg -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg-file-9c7f37cf-a5e9-e1cd-c4fa-2a26218a1a23